# Exoplayer v2, live video stream

Tags: android, android-videoview, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to replace video view with ExoPlayer for live streaming in my app.

i am unable to find any example on ExoPlayer to replace my code with `videoView.setVideoURI("")` and the implementation for live video.

Anyone implemented can please help?

Thanks

Comment: https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

**add bellow compile to your gradle:**

```
//Video Playback library
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.+'
```

**Add below line to your xml file:**

```
 <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:resize_mode="fill"></com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView>
```

**Write celow code in your Activity:**

```
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private TrackSelector trackSelector;
    // replace URL with your url/path
    private String urlToPlay;

    //I have used butterknife you can bind view as per your convinience
    @BindView(R.id.video_player)
    SimpleExoPlayerView feedVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setUpVideo();
    }
    private void setUpVideo() {
        // 1. Create a default TrackSelector
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
                new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        trackSelector = new 
        DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        // 2. Create the player
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, 
                 trackSelector);

        feedVideo.setPlayer(player);
        setUpVideoData();
    }

 private void setUpVideoData() {
        // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"), bandwidthMeter);
        // Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(urlToPlay),
                dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
        // Prepare the player with the source.
        player.prepare(videoSource);

        // Auto Play video as soon as it buffers
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

   @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        pauseLivePreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        resumeLivePreview();
    }

    private void resumeLivePreview() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }
    }

    private void pauseLivePreview() {
        if (player != null) {
        if (feedVideo != null && feedVideo.getPlayer() != null) {
            feedVideo.getPlayer().release();
        }
    }
```

Refrences
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer
https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html

Comment: i didn't get you can you please elaborate why to do you need seek bar onpause and on resume